# Use of Unassigned local variable even though it is declared

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I am trying to make a simple calculator and I'm getting this error "Use of Unassigned Variable 'operation'

it only gives the error at the start of the statement in one line

here:  if (**operation** == "x")

whole thing:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        int firstNumber;
        int secondNumber;
        string operation;
        int answer;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello welcome to Eral's Calculator");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter the first number for the equation");
        firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number for the equation");
        secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        if (operation == "x")
        {

            answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + "x" + secondNumber + " = " + answer);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (operation == "+")
        {
            answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + "+" + secondNumber + " = " + answer);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        else if (operation == "-")
        {
            answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + "-" + secondNumber + " = " + answer);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (operation == "/")
        {
            answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + "/" + secondNumber + "=" + answer);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not how you calculate, Try Again?");  
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please point to the line where you **believe** you are assigning to `operation`. _If you can't point to that line, that is why the compiler is complaining._

Comment: (Using `"x"` for an operator is asking for trouble if/once you add *variables, identifiers, names*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture a value for `operation`.

e.g.:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the operation type");
    operation = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like operation is never set to anything?